Trill with “no turn” in Lilypond
I'm looking for the best way to add a “no turn” annotation to a trill. It should be displayed above or below the trill extender line, right-aligned to the end of the extender line.


You can do this like this:
{
  <<
    {
      \override TrillSpanner.bound-details.right.text =
      \markup\lower #2.5 \with-dimensions #'(0 . 0) #'(+inf.0 . -inf.0) \right-align\italic "no turn"
      c'''2\startTrillSpan <>\stopTrillSpan
    }
    \\
    {
      c''16 16( b') b'( g') g' c'8
    }
  >>
}

The \with-dimensions is to allow the trill spanner to go all the way (#'(0 . 0)) and to avoid Lilypond having to shift the Spanner up unnecessarily.
This could cause some collision issues down the line though.
